# awk or sed or perl: remove only characters on specific position

Tags: sed, awk, perl

I have multiple files to rename

```
    leng-1494-001
    leng-1464-002
    leng-2414-004
    leng-7894-005
    leng-1323-006
```

I want to rename it

```
    ferr-1494-001
    ferr-1464-002
    ferr-2414-004
    ferr-7894-005
    ferr-1323-006
```

I know how to do for ferr and leng,but how to replace characters from 6 to 10( 1464,7894) with  blank line for example,or string like aaaa bbbb cccc using sed?
Also awk or perl solution is welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Replace them with what?

Comment: With blank line for example,or string like aaaa bbbb cccc now edit question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSIXly:

```
$ sed -e 's/-[^-]*-/-/' file
    leng-001
    leng-002
    leng-004
    leng-005
    leng-006
```

Comment: Probably my english is not good,i want to remove only the part from 6 to 10  on example 1464 2414 etc

Comment: I try the edited,is working,but perl solution is more adaptable for other files maybe called leng-prov-help-293494-udd :)

Comment: But i like this for files filename-badstring-continue,so i accept as solution

Answer (score 2):

Using sed:

```
sed -r 's/(.*[a-zA-Z]{4}\-)([0-9]{4})/\1aaaa/g'
```

Comment: echo ferr-1234-006 |sed -r 's/(.+leng\-)([0-9]{4})/\1aaaa/g' return ferr-1234-006

Comment: In your question you said the original file names contain "leng". Anyways, modified accordingly. Now it should work fine for "leng", "ferr" or whatever.

Comment: Why the negative vote??

Comment: Error,sorry i have replaced my vote with positive but your answer doesn't work on my problem

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution using perl substring function

```
echo     leng-1323-006|perl -lpe 'substr($_, 5, 5) = "";'
```

return correctly

```
leng-006
```

I hve removed from position 5 the 5 bad characters include the -